# Are module level variables safe when used with uWSGI?

Tags: python, django, scope, uwsgi

I am seeing an odd error where a variable I create at the module scope -- as in, at the top of the file before any classes or functions are defined -- is behaving differently over time.  This variable (let's call it `_cache`) gets pulled into my classes:

```
_cache = None

class XMLGenerator(object):
    global _cache

    def __init__(self, parms):
        if _cache is None:
             _cache = expensive_query(parms)
```

The results of this cache can be different depending on the context of the request coming into the web services, but I am seeing differing behavior in the resulting XML output between calls to the same service:  I can restart the server and everything is great, but eventually the anomalous behavior begins again.

Is uWSGI preserving state between requests somehow?

Comment: Can you describe the anomalous behavior?  Also, if you didn't think uWSGI preserved the value between requests, then what are you caching in _cache?

Comment: Also, your class definition is wrong: parms shouldn't be both a base class and a parameter to the initializer, right?

Comment: XMLGenerator is called multiple times to build one XML representation of a collection.  There are various objects that need to be cached between hits, otherwise we get ``n+1`` issues.  I'm seeing the tags generated as expected in the first few requests, then it just... stops.  Also, good catch on the example.  It was just a quick abstraction of the concept.  I've edited it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to circle back and explain what happened here.  Global variables are, in fact, not "refreshed" between requests to the same service in uWSGI. Thus, if you create a module level variable, it will carry state between multiple requests. This, obviously, was not what I intended; so I ended up passing a caching object around between the different calls into `XMLGenerator`.  It caused the API to be quite ugly, but avoided the issue with module-level variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this with multiple workers than you probably want to use uwsig's CachingFramework:

```
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/CachingFramework
```

Otherwise I believe _cache can be different across the workers.

Also, you could test with uwsgi --processes 1 to see if the problem goes away.